# Error building Setup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, compiler-errors, installation

I am building a setup in VS2008 C#.
When build is clicked **WARNING: Unable to copy the schema file '(null)'** message .

I have VS2008 + VS 2010 installed. Both were working fine.
For some reason it is happening today in VS2008.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your registry permissions ?

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Deployment\Schema

Comment: i did check . DefaultMSISchemaFile and DefaultMSMSchemaFile has corresponding paths value set